# How to use with_column method to create a calculated column in Polars Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I was trying to create a new computed column based on existing column in polars rust DataFrame. There is a pyspark like `with_column` method available for that. But in the api documentation there is no example. Here is a example dataframe:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

fn example() {
    let df = df!["foo" => ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C"],
        "val1" => [1, 2, 2, 4, 2],
        "val2" => [1, 2, 2, 4, 2],
        ].unwrap();
    // newcolumn ration = val1/val2
    // df.with_column(...)
    println!("{}", df);

fn main{
    example()
}
```

I want to create a `ration` column which will calculate the ration between val1 and val 2 but there is no example available in the API [documentation](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.with_column). Also there is another issue. The with column method might also need the `col` type to wrap the columns like pyspark but `polars::prelute::*` does not brings the `col` type into scope. Or may be some features needed to be enabled in the cargo file.

I am using latest version of Polars 0.22.8.

Does any one knows how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial idea works with the lazy API:

```ini
# Cargo.toml
# ...
[dependencies]
polars = { version = "0.22.8", features = ["lazy"] }
```

```rust
// src/main.rs
use polars::prelude::*;

fn example() -> DataFrame {
    let df = df!["foo" => ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C"],
    "val1" => [1, 2, 2, 4, 2],
    "val2" => [1, 2, 2, 4, 2],
    ]
    .unwrap();

    df.lazy()
        .with_column((col("val1") / col("val2")).alias("ration"))
        .collect()
        .unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let df = example();
    println!("{:?}", df);
}
```

Output:

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┬────────┐
│ foo ┆ val1 ┆ val2 ┆ ration │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---    │
│ str ┆ i32  ┆ i32  ┆ i32    │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╪════════╡
│ A   ┆ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A   ┆ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B   ┆ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B   ┆ 4    ┆ 4    ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ C   ┆ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ 1      │
└─────┴──────┴──────┴────────┘
```

Comment: It seems like most of the advance features needed Lazy API. Not sure why the package wrier considered lazy as optional features.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a nasty way of doing that. I believe there must be a better way. After reading some part of the API doc I got the info: The argument of `df.with_column()` must have to be a type which implements the `InToIter` trait. Another part of the doc it says the type Series has a implementation of that Trait. So first I have created a new series and then provided the series into the function which will add a new column as follows:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

fn example() -> DataFrame {
    let mut df = df!["foo" => ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C"],
        "val1" => [1, 2, 2, 4, 2],
        "val2" => [1, 2, 2, 4, 2],
        ].unwrap();
    let ration = Series::new(
        "ration",
         df.column("val1").unwrap()/df.column("val2").unwrap()
    );
    let _ = df.with_column(ration).unwrap();
    df
}

fn main() {
    let df = example();
    println!("{}", df);
}
```

Result:

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┬────────┐
│ foo ┆ val1 ┆ val2 ┆ ration │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---    │
│ str ┆ i32  ┆ i32  ┆ i32    │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╪════════╡
│ A   ┆ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A   ┆ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B   ┆ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B   ┆ 4    ┆ 4    ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ C   ┆ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ 1      │
└─────┴──────┴──────┴────────┘
```